# why WindowProperties displayed instead of null when expanding Window.prototype in chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

[image: expanding]

```
Window.prototype.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__; //returns null
```

But when expanding `__proto__` of `Object.prototype at Window.prototype.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__`
the prototype is shown as `WindowProperties`.

Please explain why it is `WindowProperties` instead of `null`, only when expanding in chrome DevTools.

Comment: What exactly are you expanding? Where? How?

Comment: expanding objects in Chrome dev tools

Comment: Which objects? Please [edit] your post and provide the necessary steps to reproduce. You talk about `Object.prototype`, but also about `Window.prototype`. How are these connected?

Comment: Please check the steps in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZV8d.jpg

Comment: What you’ve shown in the screenshot is `Window.prototype.__proto__`, not `Window.prototype.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__`. _[[Prototype]]_ is not the same as `__proto__`.

Comment: Isn't [[Prototype]] another version of deprecated ```__proto__``` ? Eg ```Window.prototype.__proto__``` has same value as Window.prototype > [[Prototype]] , ``` Window.prototype.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(Window.prototype); //returns true ```

Comment: Per ecmascript [https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-4.3.5] : ```[[Prototype]]``` means The prototype of this object. Also ```.__proto__``` points to the prototype of this object, so ```[[Prototype]]``` and ```.__proto__``` should be same.

Comment: Still, `__proto__` is just a property which may be inherited via the prototype chain. `Window.prototype.hasOwnProperty("__proto__")` is `false`, so the property lookup occurs further down the prototype chain. _[[Prototype]]_ points to the next link in the prototype chain.

Comment: Huh, [finally](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=817305)!

Comment: I cannot reproduce. [This is how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK7KR.png). As expected, `Object.prototype` has a `__proto__` getter/setter, and no [[prototype]] on its own (I might have expected *[[prototype]]: `null`* maybe)

Comment: It looks like this is only showing up in Chrome Dev and Firefox browsers.

Comment: @SnmJpa In FF, it looks different as well. For me, there's (next to the `get __proto__` and `set __proto__` definitions) as `__proto__` property with a little double arrow that says "*Invoke getter*". When you click on it, the getter appears to be evaluated against the root object (the one you logged), and that has the `WindowProperties { … }` object as its prototype. Nothing unexpected.